# Wait for promise on each item in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm using ssh2-sftp-client in Node to download a series of files. Once the files are downloaded, I need to check each one to see if it's a CSV, then check my database to see if it was previously imported.

I'm using promises and having trouble with sequencing. I think I'm getting close after several hours of research, but can't quite get it over the line.

Here's the code:

```
const isFileCSV = (filename) => {

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        if (filename.endsWith('.csv')) {
            result = 'true';
            resolve(result);
        } else {
            result = 'false';
            resolve(result);
        }
    });
}

const wasFileImported = (filename) => {     
    // Return a new promise
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        // Core function
        con.query(`CALL wasFileImported('${filename}')`, (err, results) => {
            console.log('02 Checking if file was previously imported.');    
            if (err) {
                logEntry('error', `Error searching database: ${err}`);
                reject(Error('false'));
            } else {
                result = results[0][0]['importCheck'];
                resolve(result);
            }
        })
    });
}

const importFile = (file) => {
    isFileCSV(file).then((result) => {
        console.log(`01a File ${file} ends with csv? ${result}`);
        result = result.toLowerCase();
        return result;
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result === 'false') {
            console.log(`01b ${result} = Not csv, log it and skip to next.`);
            return;
        } else if (result === 'true') {
            console.log(`01b ${result} = It is csv, go to next step`);
            return result;
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        wasFileImported('file').then((result) => {
            console.log('03 checked import, result: ', result);
            return result.toLowerCase();
        }).then((result) => {
            switch(result) {
                case 'false':
                    console.log('04a download file and log it');
                    break;
                case 'true':
                    console.log('04b skip it and log the skip');
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('04c unknown error, log the skip');                         
            }           
        })              
    })              
}

logEntry('info', `attempting to connnect to ${config.destination.host}`);
console.log('00 start');

sftp.connect(crmConfig).then(() => {
    logEntry('info', `connected to ${config.destination.host}`);
    return sftp.list(ordersUrl);
}).then((data) => {
    fileList = [];
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, val]) => {
        fileList.push(val['name']);
    });
    return fileList;
}).then((fileList) => {
    let promises = [];

    fileList.forEach((file) => {
        promises.push(importFile(file));
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
        console.log('Done');
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error');
    });
});
```

What I expect to see is the following:

```
00 start
01a File daily.csv ends with csv? true
01b true = It is csv, go to next step
02 Checking if file was previously imported.
03 checked import, result:  FALSE
04a download file and log it
01a File daily072418.csv ends with csv? true
01b true = It is csv, go to next step
02 Checking if file was previously imported.
03 checked import, result:  FALSE
04a download file and log it
01a File test.csw ends with csv? false
01b false = Not csv, log it and skip to next.
02 Checking if file was previously imported.
03 checked import, result:  FALSE
04a download file and log it
Done
```

What I'm actually getting is this:

```
00 start
01a File daily.csv ends with csv? true
01a File daily072418.csv ends with csv? true
01a File test.csw ends with csv? false
01b true = It is csv, go to next step
01b true = It is csv, go to next step
01b false = Not csv, log it and skip to next.
Done
02 Checking if file was previously imported.
03 checked import, result:  FALSE
04a download file and log it
02 Checking if file was previously imported.
03 checked import, result:  FALSE
04a download file and log it
02 Checking if file was previously imported.
03 checked import, result:  FALSE
04a download file and log it
```

Earlier versions did not use Promise.all but still generated the same result. I also tried changing resolve to return in wasFileImported and isFileCSV, but then I just get "00 Start" followed by "Done," with no execution in between.

Clearly I'm not iterating through the array correctly for what I'm intending. What's the best way to do this so everything is done sequentially?

**EDIT**
For anyone else who needs it, here's the final working code with thanks to @jordan-peterson and @spakmad:

```
const isFileCSV = (filename) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        if (filename.endsWith('.csv')) {
            result = 'true';
            resolve(result);
        } else {
            result = 'false';
            resolve(result);
        }
    });
}

const wasFileImported = (filename) => {     
    // Return a new promise
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        // Core function
        con.query(`CALL wasFileImported('${filename}')`, (err, results) => {
            console.log('02 Checking if file was previously imported.');    
            if (err) {
                logEntry('error', `Error searching database: ${err}`);
                reject(Error('false'));
            } else {
                result = results[0][0]['importCheck'];
                resolve(result);
            }
        })
    });
}

const importFile = (file) => {
    return isFileCSV(file).then((result) => {
        console.log(`01a File ${file} ends with csv? ${result}`);
        result = result.toLowerCase();
        return result;
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result === 'false') {
            console.log(`01b ${result} = Not csv, log it and skip to next.`);
            return;
        } else if (result === 'true') {
            console.log(`01b ${result} = It is csv, go to next step`);
            return result;
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        return wasFileImported('file').then((result) => {
            console.log('03 checked import, result: ', result);
            return result.toLowerCase();
        }).then((result) => {
            switch(result) {
                case 'false':
                    console.log('04a download file and log it');
                    break;
                case 'true':
                    console.log('04b skip it and log the skip');
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('04c unknown error, log the skip');                         
            }           
        })              
    })              
}

console.log('00 start');

sftp.connect(crmConfig).then(() => {
    logEntry('info', `connected to ${config.destination.host}`);
    return sftp.list(ordersUrl);
}).then((data) => {
    fileList = [];
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, val]) => {
        fileList.push(val['name']);
    });
    return fileList;
}).then((fileList) => {
    let promiseChain = Promise.resolve()

    fileList.forEach((file) => {
        promiseChain = promiseChain.then(() => {
            return importFile(file)
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: use Promise.each() instead of Promise.all(). Or alternatively use async/await

Comment: FYI, there's no reason for `isFileCSV()` to return a promise as shown.  It can be a normal synchronous function that returns a boolean.

Comment: You're running all your operations in parallel so their internal order is somewhat random and not predictable.  If you want to sequence them, then you have to actually code them to be sequenced.  Usually, using `await` is the simplest way to sequence things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `importFile`, an asynchronous method, three times in a row, so it is moving through those at the same time. If you want one executed after another, what I like to do is this.

```
let promiseChain = Promise.resolve()
myFiles.forEach((file) => {
   promiseChain = promiseChain.then(() => {
      return importFile(file)
   }
}
```

each iteration over the loop appends another `then` to the `Promise` in `promiseChain` that does not move forward until the first `then` returns. The first `then` appended is advanced to immediately because at that point `promiseChain` is `Promise.resolve()`

This can be done with a `reduce` too.

```
myFiles.reduce((acc, file) => acc.then(() => importFiles(file))), Promise.resolve())
```

Comment: Thanks @nschwan94, that makes sense, and I'm getting closer. Now the output looks like this:

00 start 01a 01b 01a 01b 01a 01b     02 03 04     02 03 04    02 03 04

Not sure what I'm missing after 01b, as that's returning a result to the next part of the chain.

Comment: Not sure, but like some of the other comments say, in `importFile` make sure you write `return isFileCSV` and `return wasFileImported`. Almost there!

Comment: That did it! The combination of this solution plus the comment from @jordan-davidson to add return in front of the isFileCSV and wasFileImported function calls inside importFile did the trick. And spakmad, not sure where I came up with the nschwan94 tag in my first reply to you. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like importFile is not returning a promise. This means the list of promises is full of `[undefined, undefined...]`. You can check this with a `console.log()`. First step in debugging "PRINT ALL THE THINGS!". put a return statement in front of 
`isFileCsv(file).then((result) => {`.  At least that is why 'Done' is in the middle. The reason your csv checks are at the top is because they are not async so your code does all of that first before giving control over to the code handling the async parts.

Answer (score 0):

importFile has to be a promise, try with this :

```
const importFile = function(file){

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        isFileCSV(file).then((result) => {
            console.log(`01a File ${file} ends with csv? ${result}`);
            result = result.toLowerCase();

            if (result === 'false') {
                console.log(`01b ${result} = Not csv, log it and skip to next.`);
            } else if (result === 'true') {
                console.log(`01b ${result} = It is csv, go to next step`);
            }

            wasFileImported('file').then((result) => {
                console.log('03 checked import, result: ', result);

                switch(result) {
                    case 'false':
                        console.log('04a download file and log it');
                        break;
                    case 'true':
                        console.log('04b skip it and log the skip');
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log('04c unknown error, log the skip');                         
                }

                return resolve(result);
            }) 

        });

    });     
}
```

Comment: or you can just `return isFileCSV(file...` as that chain returns a promise